# In a C# public method, what does the `int` indicate apart from the type integer? 

Tags: c#, methods, int

In C#, when defining a public method like:

```
public int myMethod(String someString)
{  
   //code  
}
```

What does the `int` indicate apart from the type integer? What confuses me is that the method is using a String as arguments in this case.

Comment: For the method's return value.

Comment: The return type.

Comment: A function may or may not return a value. Your function falls in the former case., and it returns integer value.

Comment: See [Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx) and [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) and [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: Sorry this is a complete beginner's question. I did do some research on the Internet beforehand. I knew about Integer but did not that it was for return value. The answers below were extremely helpful! How could I formulate it for you not to vote it down? I will always look in the above links before posting a question in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the return type of the method. In this case a 32-bit signed integer with a range of

```
-2,147,483,648 .. +2,147,483,647
```

It corresponds to the .NET type `System.Int32`. `int` is just a handy C# alias for it.

You would return a value like this

```
public int Square(int i)
{
    return i * i;
}
```

And you could call it like this

```
int sqr = Square(7); // Returns 49
// Or
double d = Math.Sin(Square(3));
```

If you do not need the return value, you can safely ignore it.

```
int i;
Int32.TryParse("123", out i); // We ignore the `bool` return value here.
```

If you have no return value you would use the keyword `void` in place of the type. `void` is not a real type.

```
public void PrintSquare(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * i);
}
```

And you would call it like this

```
PrintSquare(7);
```

---

The method in your example accepts a `string` as input parameter and returns an `int` as result. A practical example would be a method that counts the number of vowels in a `string`.

```
public int NumberOfVowels(string s)
{
    const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (vowels.Contains(s[i])) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Olivier is correct. `int` is signed because it can hold negative numbers. In contrast, `uint` is unsigned, and can only hold positive numbers.

Comment: Yes, `uint` has the range `0 .. 4,294,967,295`.

Comment: The "and you would call it like this" lines may suggest to new programmers that you have to assign the return value of a method that does not return `void`.  This isn't the case.

Comment: @Will. You are right. I clarified my statement and added an example with a `string` as input parameter and an `int` as return value. (There might exist a more efficient algorithm; however, this is not the point here.)

Answer (score 6):

It stands for "integer", and it means the method returns an integer number of 32 bits, also known in C# as `Int32`.

Comment: And for more information, please see this article: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/

Comment: I assumed that @arthurmani knew what an int was already but didn't understand about the return type.

Answer (score 5):

As previously stated, it's what the method returns.

For example:

```
public string x()
{
 return 5;
}
```

Would error. `5` is definitely not a string!

```
public int x()
{
 return 5;
}
```

Would be correct; since 5 can be considered an int (Short for integer, which is, basically, just a number which cannot have a decimal point. There's also float, double, long and decimal, which are worth reading about)

There must be no way of it not returning, for example, if you do:

```
public int x()
{
 if (false)
 {
  return 5;
 }
}
```

It will error because if the expression is false (It is of course) it won't be returning an int, it won't return anything.

If you use the keyword `void`, it means it does *not* return anything. Ex:

```
public void x()
{
 someFunction("xyz");
}
```

It's fine that it doesn't return as it's a `void` method.

I don't think you're new to programming judging by your reputation, but just in case, when you return something you pass it back from the method, for example:

```
int x;

public int seven()
{
 return 7;
}

x = seven();
```

`x` will become the return value of the function `seven`.

Note that the 'dynamic' type works here:

```
public dynamic x(int x, int y)
{
 if (x == y)
 {
  return "hello";
 }
 return 5
}
```

But if you're new to C# don't get caught up in dynamic typing just yet. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is the *type* of the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is correct here but the definition from msdn:

> "Int32 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with values that range from negative 2,147,483,648 (which is represented by the Int32.MinValue constant) through positive 2,147,483,647 (which is represented by the Int32.MaxValue constant. The .NET Framework also includes an unsigned 32-bit integer value type, UInt32, which represents values that range from 0 to 4,294,967,295."

Found here on MSDN: [Int32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.INT32%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

I suggest you read the documentation found in the link above. It is extremely useful.